# Double Intergral Question on Example

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

The question in my book is:

Find the volume of the solid enclosed by the surface z = $x\sec^2y$ and the planes $z = 0, \, x = 0, \, x = 2, \, y = 0, \, y = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

I understand how to solve the problem:
$\int _0^2\int _0^{\pi/4}x\sec^2y\:dy\, dx$ which comes out to $2$.

My question is, what was the point in telling us that the solid was enclosed by the the plane $z = 0$. Why did it include that? What was I supposed to deduce from that?

Comment: It's superfluous information in this case, since your integrand is non-negative for $x>0$. If that was not the case, it would be an important constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral is actually

$$\int _0^2\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}xsec^2y\color{red}{-(0)}\:dydx\:\:\:$$

Suppose it is bound by $z=-1$ instead, it would become

$$\int _0^2\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}xsec^2y\color{red}{-(-1)}\:dydx\:\:\:$$

If it is not specified, the interested region is not bounded.